# SwiftUI CoreData boolean

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I'm having some confusion with `CoreData` using SwiftUI, I'm just doing an example project for a `Toggle`. I set the newly created item in `PersistenceController` but the toggle always remains off. I don't have much experience using `CoreData`, my previous question I about CoreData was incorrect and I was misinformed about a fix.

PersistenceController

```swift
static var preview: PersistenceController = {
    let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
    let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
    for _ in 0..<10 {
        let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
        newItem.bool = false
    }
    do {
        try viewContext.save()
    } catch {
        let nsError = error as NSError
        fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
    }
    return result
}()
```

ContentView

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.bool, ascending: true)], animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle("", isOn: Binding<Bool>(
                get: { self.items.first?.bool ?? false },
                set: {
                    self.items.first?.bool = $0
                    try? viewContext.save()
                }
            ))
            .labelsHidden()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As it goes from the name of variable, `preview` is only used in preview, at least in newly generated project. So on real run your database if empty
2. Using `sortDescriptors` your list of items is sorted ascending by `bool`. This means that as soon as you set first item `bool` to true, it gets moved to the end of the list, and you're reading `bool` value from an other object

To create a new `Item` at start when your database is empty, you need to wait persistent store load, fetch items and check that there're no items, in this case - create a new one. Replace `PersistenceController` `init` with following:

```
init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
    container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "SwiftUICodeDataPlayground")
    if inMemory {
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
    }
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { [self] (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
        if (try? container.viewContext.fetch(Item.fetchRequest()).isEmpty) != false {
            let newItem = Item(context: container.viewContext)
            newItem.bool = false
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I haven't been able to find much on `CoreData` in SwiftUI. How would I do so on a real run? I also currently only have one `bool` value set, if I were to add more that would most likely cause problems.

Comment: @cole I've added code which will create a new `Item` if your database is empty